# Differential equation problem in Maple

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple

I have differential equation $x\cdot\sqrt{4+y^2}\,dx + y\cdot\sqrt{1+x^2}\,dy = 0$, which is simple to solve on paper, but I have problem solving it with Maple (I use 10th, tried on 14th also). When applying dsolve it complains that it is not ODE.
Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try dividing through by $dx$? This will eliminate $dx$ and replace $dy$ with $y'$.

Comment: I believe the command you are looking for is "dsolve(x*sqrt(4+y(x)^2)+y(x)*sqrt(1+x^2)*diff(y(x),x), y(x))"

Comment: @Fabian Could post as an answer. Because it is perfectly working solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you are looking for is

`dsolve(x*sqrt(4+y(x)^2)+y(x)*sqrt(1+x^2)*diff(y(x),x), y(x))`.

Comment: It looks better if you include code in backticks (\`code\`): `dsolve(x*sqrt(4+y(x)^2)+y(x)*sqrt(1+x^2)*diff(y(x),x), y(x))`